# Why there is unexpected result in arc4random() % n?

Tags: objective-c, arc4random, underflow

i have

```
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    CGFloat longerA = ((arc4random() % 80) - 40) / 100.0f;
    NSLog(@"%f",longerA);
}
```

and the result is

```
2013-09-20 11:41:30.801 ****[7025:a0b] 0.390000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.801 ****[7025:a0b] 0.080000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.801 ****[7025:a0b] 0.380000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.801 ****[7025:a0b] 42949672.000000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.802 ****[7025:a0b] 0.060000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.802 ****[7025:a0b] 0.080000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.802 ****[7025:a0b] 0.290000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.802 ****[7025:a0b] 42949672.000000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.803 ****[7025:a0b] 0.350000
2013-09-20 11:41:30.803 ****[7025:a0b] 0.180000
```

i just cant understand why there are results 42949672.000000

Please explain me why this is happening

As i "understand"
It must take random(80) - 40 and result / 100.0f so i just don't understand how this (arc4random() % 80) can be more then 79.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arc4random` function is documented to return and `u_int32_t`. That sounds like an unsigned type, so that when you roll a number < 40 and then subtract 40, you get an [arithmetic underflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow). That’s where the big number comes from (2^32 – something).

Comment: Thank you for the answer i will try to get it from this point now. I will mark as Answered when i really get this.

Comment: As i understand i have type that don't support numbers that are  < 0 so it trow me a mistake? when result is < 0?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Read something about signed vs. unsigned number types and arithmetic overflow and underflow.

Answer (score 2):

`arc4random` returns unsigned integers, which can not be below 0. Subtracting 40 will underflow and wrap around to something close to the maximum value.

You also have [modulo bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) in your function (some values will be more common than others). Correct for this by using `arc4random_uniform(80)` instead of doing `% 80`. Thus the correct solution is:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    CGFloat longerA = (((int)arc4random_uniform(80)) - 40) / 100.0f;
    NSLog(@"%f",longerA);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i don't like to use casts. Also i already  remake this line like CGFloat longerA = (arc4random() % 80) / 100.0f - 0.4f;

Comment: Then you still retain the modulo bias. The values between 0 and 16 will be twice as comman as 17-79. Use arc4random_uniform instead of % 80.

Comment: I have read modulo bias. But why 0 - 16 will be twice as comman as 17-79? As i understand i will have some numbers that will have not 1/80 but 1/80 + some_really_small_value. Max rand in u_int32_t is kinda big . But yes you are right i must avoid this low possibility too.